# get rows where queryColumns > tableColumns as well as queryColumns = tableColumns

Tags: php, mysql

SORRY I COULDN'T THINK OF BETTER TITLE

usually we have a `table` and we have a `query`  and we want rows which in them

`query = table` but what if also want the rows if `query > table`

so here is an example ,  lets say we have a website which connects people who wants some services to companies , we have 4 services `a,b,c,d,`

so a user would select his desired services an we store them in database

```
wanted :
+-----------+----------+---------+------+-------- 
| user_id   | a        | b       | c    | d     |
+-----------+----------+---------+------+--------
|  23       | 1        |   0     | 1    | 0     |
+-----------+----------+---------+---------------

for example this guy wants a,c
```

now a company would come to our website and says we offer `a,c`

so i query

```
 $query = "select user_id from wanted where a=1 && c =1 ";
```

i get user 21 and i would connect them to each other .

but what if the company offers services `a,b,c`

```
 $query = "select user_id from wanted where a=1 && b =1 && c=1 ";
```

it wouldn't return user 21 , but it should .... they are not perfect match but service required by user  21 is covered by this company

i know i should to the process other way around and first store companies and let the users search for them and i wouldn't have this problem , but this how this website works

so what are my options ? anything can be done ?

**pleas note** that i can't use `OR ||`  cuz the company should cover all the needs of customer 
so if i have a user `x` which  wants `a,b,c` and company with `a,b,d` 
the query

```
select * from wanted where a = 1 || b = 1 || d = 1
```

would return user `x` and thats wrong cuz the company doesn't cover desired service `c`

Answer (score 0):

I would use OR to get all users which are at least in one service:

```
$query = "select user_id from wanted where a = 1 OR b = 1 OR c = 1 ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost seems like too simple of a fix, but how about OR instead of AND?

`$query = "select user_id from wanted where a=1 or b =1 or c=1 ";`

Answer (score 0):

In your senario you could use or rather than and so

```
where a=1 || b =1 || c=1 ";
```

which would return any customer who wants product a, b or c bit not necessarily all of them.

Personally I would change the structure of the database so I had a products table and a customers tables then a 1 to many join between the two tables. That would allow you to query like:

```
where product.product_id IN (1,2,3);
```